# retrieve json value by key

Tags: jquery, json, servlets

Below is success function for my ajax:

```
success: function(responseJson) 
{
    var receivedData = [];

    $.each(responseJson.jsonArray, function(index) 
    {
        $.each(responseJson.jsonArray[index], function(key, value)
        {
            var point = [];

            point.push(key);
            point.push(value);
            receivedData.push(point);
        });
    });

    if(receivedData["arrayData3"] === "data3")
    {
        alert("Edit Customer profile successfully!");
    }
},
```

From code above, i push all data into `receivedData` variable, I can print all key and value out just by print the variable `receivedData`, but how can I get specific value by their key? `receivedData["arrayData3"]` will get undefined.
Below is code from my servlet:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject data =  new JSONObject();
data.put("arrayData1", "data1");
data.put("arrayData2", "data2");
data.put("arrayData3", "data3");
array.add(data);
json.put("jsonArray", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the jsonarray with the jsonobject.

Actually,the `resposeJson` is like the code below.

```
resposeJson = {
    jsonArray:[
        {
            arrarData1: "data1"
        },
        {
            arrarData2: "data2"
        },
        {
            arrarData3: "data3"
        },
    ]
}
```

So,you ajax code can be writed like below

```
success: function(responseJson) 
{
var receivedData = [];

$.each(responseJson.jsonArray, function(index, elem) 
{
    receivedData.push(elem); 
});

if(receivedData["arrayData3"] === "data3")
{
    alert("Edit Customer profile successfully!");
}
},
```

Comment: I replaced my `$.each` function with yours, but still get undefined while alert the value of `(receivedData["arrayData3"]`

Comment: @Newbie sorry,i just get something wrong. it shoud be `var receiveData = {}` and `$.extend(receiveData, elem)` in my `$.each` function. finally, you need a object.